# automatic add the product's Set Product as New from Date

Tags: magento-1.9

My aim is to create the product's **New From** and **New To** date fields to be filled **automatically**, We do not have to fill those dates. So basically i want the New From Date should be the same when product is being edited/added and In the field New to date, i want to automatically assign the date after 3 month's date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create an observer for the event `catalog_product_save_before` that can look like this:

```
public function setNewDates($observer) 
{
    $dateModel = Mage::getSingleton('core/date');
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product->setNewsFromDate($dateModel->gmtDate());
    $product->setNewsToDate($dateModel->gmtDate(null, mktime(0,0,0, date('m') + 3, date('d'), date('Y') )));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius, It worked for me. I have used this event 'catalog_product_prepare_save' .